# Indy download selected file from the listbox

Tags: delphi, indy

I never used Indy and am struggling to learn the basic. Took me some time to figure out how to populate the listbox. Now that I have done that how can I download the selected file in the listbox ?
I tried :

```
procedure TFTP.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
i:integer;
begin
for i := 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 do begin
if ListBox1.Selected[i] then begin
IdFTP1.Get(listbox1.Selected[i]);
end;
end;
end;
```

But I am getting :

> [dcc32 Error] FTP_Form.pas(75): E2250 There is no overloaded version
>   of 'Get' that can be called with these arguments

Or do I need to use a savedialog too? Please help me with this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way  ....

```
procedure TFTP.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
Name{, Line}: String;
begin
Name := IdFTP1.DirectoryListing.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex].FileName;
SaveDialog1.FileName := Name;
if SaveDialog1.Execute then begin
IdFTP1.Get(Name, SaveDialog1.FileName, true);
end;
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

`ListBox1.Selected[i]` is a `Boolean`. Note that in the previous line you wrote:

```
if ListBox1.Selected[i] then begin
```

Now, look at the `TIdFTP.Get()` method. It has two overloads:

```
procedure Get(const ASourceFile: string; ADest: TStream; 
  AResume: Boolean = false); overload;
procedure Get(const ASourceFile, ADestFile: string; const ACanOverwrite: boolean = false; 
  AResume: Boolean = false); overload;
```

You need to provide:

- the source filename of the remote file you want to download.
- a destination filename or stream to receive the content of the remote file.

I don't know where you intend to obtain these. Presumably the filename comes from the ListBox, which would therefore be `ListBox1.Items[i]`.

What do you want to do with the content you download? Keep it in memory? Save it to a file? Something else?  What destination you supply depends on your answers to those questions.

My advice to you is to put the ListBox to one side for the moment, and write a simpler program, one without any UI, that simply downloads a single file from the FTP server. Use a local filename or a `TFileStream` to save the downloaded content to your local disk. Check that the contents are what you expect. Once you can download one file, you can download any number of files, to other kinds of destinations.

Once you have mastered that, move on to the user interface. Spend some time learning how the ListBox control works, how you populate it, how you read back strings from it, how you test for selection, and so on.

Only when you have a good understanding of all parts involved, then you should you try to fit them together.

Comment: How do i convert ListBox1.Selected[i] to string so I can use it ?

Comment: It's a `Boolean`. That means it can have one of two values, `False` or `True`. Do you really want to convert that to a string?

Comment: I decided to use the savedialog so I need to pass the value of listbox item as savedialog.filename.

Comment: I suggest that you read the second part of my answer. You are making the common beginner mistake of trying to solve your problems in the context of a complete program. Break the problem down. First of all work out how to obtain file names. Separately work out how to download files, given a file name. Keep these tasks separate. Break them out into distinct methods.

Comment: @user3351050:  It's not a question of "converting" ListBox1.Selected[i] to a string, but how to get the string which corresponds to this boolean.  Use the Online Help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ListBox contains the remote filenames to download (such as from the `TIdFTP.DirectoryListing` property after a call to `TIdFTP.List()`):

```
procedure TFTP.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i:integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if ListBox1.Selected[i] then begin
      IdFTP1.Get(ListBox1.Items[i], 'C:\Some Local Path\' + ListBox1.Items[i]);
    end;
  end;
end;
```